# How do I swap array elements correctly in React.JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

My issue is that when performing the `blockSwap()` function, the array itself does not seem to update as intended, but the hooks in the function update their state as expected. I am not sure how the state is updating appropriately when it is dependent on the array due to the `indexOf()` methods being used. I apologize if this is poorly worded, I have thoroughly confused myself trying to figure this out.

The intended result after firing the `blockSwap()` function is that the array elements would essentially trade places as well as the "block#Order"s.

The array should log as: "2","1". And the blockOrder should log as: 1 0.

```js
const {useState} = React;

function BlockEditor() {
    let [block1Content, setBlock1Content] = useState("1");
    let [block2Content, setBlock2Content] = useState("2");

    let [block1Order, setBlock1Order] = useState(0);
    let [block2Order, setBlock2Order] = useState(1);
  
    let array = [block1Content, block2Content];

    function blockSwap() {
    [array[0], array[1]] = [array[1], array[0]];
    setBlock1Order(array.indexOf(block1Content));
    setBlock2Order(array.indexOf(block2Content));
  }
  
    function consoleLog() {
    console.log("array: ", array);
    console.log("blockOrder: ", block1Order, block2Order);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={blockSwap}>Swap Blocks</button>
      <button onClick={consoleLog}>Console Log Results</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <BlockEditor/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you don't store the array in state. If you use `useState` for `array` too, it will work correctly:

```js
const {useState} = React;

function BlockEditor() {
  let [block1Content, setBlock1Content] = useState('1');
  let [block2Content, setBlock2Content] = useState('2');

  let [block1Order, setBlock1Order] = useState(0);
  let [block2Order, setBlock2Order] = useState(1);

  let [array, setArray] = useState([block1Content, block2Content]);

  function blockSwap() {
    const copy = [...array];
    [copy[0], copy[1]] = [copy[1], copy[0]];
    setArray(copy);
    setBlock1Order(copy.indexOf(block1Content));
    setBlock2Order(copy.indexOf(block2Content));
  }

  function log() {
    console.log('array: ', array);
    console.log('blockOrder: ', block1Order, block2Order);
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={blockSwap}>Swap Blocks</button>
      <button onClick={log}>Console Log Results</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<BlockEditor />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

It would also work without creating a copy of the `array`:

```js
  function blockSwap() {
    [array[0], array[1]] = [array[1], array[0]];
    setArray(array);
    setBlock1Order(array.indexOf(block1Content));
    setBlock2Order(array.indexOf(block2Content));
  }
```